# Why active tracing disabled in my lambda even if it has required policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a lambda in AWS and in the console under Monitoring, it shows a warning:

[image]

when I click the edit button, it says: `The required permissions were not found. The Lambda console will attempt to add them to the execution role.`.

but my lambda already has this policy in its role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "xray:PutTraceSegments",
                "xray:PutTelemetryRecords",
                "xray:GetSamplingRules",
                "xray:GetSamplingTargets",
                "xray:GetSamplingStatisticSummaries"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

I wonder what else it needs in order to enable active tracing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
$ aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name my-function \
--tracing-config Mode=Active
```

I enabled the `tracing` using the above command and below mentiond permissions:

```sh
$ aws lambda get-function --function-name mylambda | jq .Configuration.TracingConfig
{
  "Mode": "Active"
}
```

And I was able to see the corresponding traces. The strange thing it was complaining the whole time in the UI for the latest version as well saying `The required permissions were not found. The Lambda console will attempt to add them to the execution role.` even though there were permissions in place.  So I am guessing it might be a bug in the UI unless someone can add more information about it.

As as I keep hitting save and it keeps adding a new policy to the `lambda execution role` and simultaneously complaining too about the same warning message.

[Using AWS Lambda with AWS X-Ray](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-xray.html#services-xray-permissions)

Only these permissions needed as described in the doc.

> Lambda needs the following permissions to send trace data to X-Ray. Add them to your function's execution role.[image]

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "xray:PutTraceSegments",
                "xray:PutTelemetryRecords"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is helpful when we have multiple versions deployed and want to test a specific version like dev/test/prod etc.

> Tracing mode is part of the version-specific configuration that is locked when you publish a version of your function. You can't change the tracing mode on a published version.